# Speedup mysql queries with regexp and order by length

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to implement a search auto-completion feature on my website. All I came up with so far is a table with search terms (cities)

```
city_id int(10) Auto Increment, Primary
city_name varchar(200) Index
```

and a query

```
select * from city_names where lower(city_name) like lower('my_search_term%) order by length(city_name) limit 10;
```

This query returns 10 cities with shortest names containing the search string, exactly what I need, but it's very slow. My guess is that the DB first searches for everything that matches the regexp, then sorts the results by length, and then picks 10 rows. I think it would be better to somehow pre-sort the data by length(city_name), so that the query stops after it reaches 10 rows that match the regexp.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to sort (collate?) the city_names column by content length? I'm not planning to alter table data, so the data need to be sorted one single time.
2. What DB engine and index structure is suitable for this table (city_names data are not unique)?
3. Is there a way to change my query in order to increase performance?

Any ideas welcome.

UPDATE:
Based on [zerkms's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594327/speedup-mysql-queries-with-regexp-and-order-by-length/21594355#21594355), I did the following:

1. Changed the collation to `latin_general_ci`. This allowed me to get rid of the LOWER(city_name) conversion.
2. Created another column (sort_index) and populated it with incremental values from ordering by length(city_name) and city_name. I.e., short names go first, and "A**" goes before "B**" for cities with the same length. Now the search is much quicker.
3. Changed default ORDER to `sort_index` ascending. Now I don't need any `ORDER` commands in my query.

The table and the query now look like:

```
sort_index int(10) Primary
city_name varchar(200)
city_id int(10) Auto Increment

select * from city_names where city_name like lower('my_search_term%) limit 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you use the `*_ci` collation then the string comparisons should be case insensitive. So `city_name LIKE LOWER('term%')` should be used.
2. Create another column and store each `city_name` column length there
3. Create composite `(city_name, city_name_length)` index (but there is a chance that the `city_name_length` won't be used though)